# Remove "Posted on" and "Posted in" from the Twenty Ten Theme

Tags: theme-twenty-ten

I just upgraded to the latest Wordpress and activated this theme.

It displays the following

---

### Hello world!

Posted on May 27, 2010 by admin

Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!

Posted in Uncategorized  | 1 Comment | Edit

---

Is there an option to remove the Posted on and Posted in ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is an **option** to do that. You can edit the theme to remove those elements, but then you will have a problem when the theme gets updated (pretty frequently for *Twenty Ten* right now.

But if you did want to do it, you have three ways to do it:

- You can edit PHP files for the presentation (e.g. loop.php) under Appearance/Editor and delete the whole section responsible for it
- You can edit functions.php that contains twentyten_posted_on and twentyten_posted_in functions to stub them out to return nothing
- You can edit CSS to make corresponding classes (entry-meta and entry-utility I believe) to be invisible. WordPress still has to do all work and it is still there in source code, but it could be the faster option. You could even use FireBug to test whether the display will look correct when you remove those.

There are better and more esoteric ways to do it (child themes), but I am not sure I could describe it in a text box.

Answer (score 0):

(1). Look for this in the theme's functions.php:
function twentyten_posted_on() { printf( __( 'Posted on %2$s by %3$s', 'twentyten' ),

(2). Removing it from single.php,for example, will only remove when you are viewing an individual post. You need to remove the unwanted stuff from loop.php as well.

(3).  You may add this code to style.css under "/* =Content" to remove: Posted by, Posten on, Posted in and comments. Much more simple. Code: .post .entry-utility, .post .entry-meta {display:none;}

Answer (score 0):

Edit the loop.php, loop-single.php files and delete the following code blocks:

```
<div class="entry-meta">
 <?php twentyten_posted_on(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-meta -->
```

================

It can also be done by putting the code snippets below into your child theme's functions.php file. Don't edit your the main functions.php of Twenty Ten (make a child theme instead) - http://wpweaver.info/themes/twenty-ten-heads-up/building-a-twenty-ten-child-theme/

```
function twentyten_posted_on() {
}

function twentyten_posted_in() {
}
```